# trying to send parts of a struct from tcp server to client in c

Tags: c, sockets, network-programming

I am trying to pass parts of a struct to the client and having a hard time with it. I tested my case 1 condition with the following print statement:

```
printf("%d %s", data[i].course, data[i].Dept);
```

This worked with no problems. Now what I am trying to do is send it through the socket. My send statement is:

```
send(connected, send_data, strlen(send_data), 0);
```

Now I tried the following statements of:

```
send_data = data[i].couurse;
strcpy(send_data, data[i].course);
send_data = atoi(data[i].course);
```

and to know avail, neither worked. I know there has to be a way and am hoping someone can show me how.
I have included the relevant parts of the code:

```
int switchInput;
int i = 0;
int connected;
int sock;
int bytes_received;
int sin_size;
int true = 1;
int tempCourse = 0;
char send_data[BUF];
char recv_data[BUF];
char tempDept[5];
char tempDay[1];
char tempTime[1];
FILE *filePointer;
sched_record data[MAX_RECORD];
filePointer = fopen (BINFILE, "rb");
```

and:

```
 while(1) {

        bytes_received = recv(connected, recv_data, BUF, 0);
        recv_data[bytes_received] = '\0';
        switchInput = atoi(recv_data);

        switch(switchInput) {

        case 1:

            fread(data, sizeof(sched_record), MAX_RECORD, filePointer);
            fclose(filePointer);
            char send_data[] = "Enter Department Name";
            send(connected, send_data, strlen(send_data), 0);
            bytes_received = recv(connected, recv_data, BUF, 0);
            recv_data[bytes_received] = '\0';
            strcpy(tempDept, recv_data);
               for (i=0; i<MAX_RECORD; i++){
                if ((strcmp(tempDept, data[i].Dept)==0) && tempCourse != data[i].course){
                        send(connected, &data[i].Dept, sizeof(data[i].Dept), 0);
                        tempCourse = data[i].course;
                        send(connected, &tempCourse, sizeof(tempCourse), 0);
                }
            }

        break;
```

In this particular case I need to send the course and department. Also is there a better way to do this? This seems kinda messy. If so, can you show me a more simplified version?

Comment: What is the return value of send?

Comment: @octopusgrabbus I am not understanding your question.

Comment: Does send return status?

Answer (score 2):

<s>You must have got compilation errors all over the place.</s>

You don't want `atoi`. you want <s>[itoa](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdlib/itoa/)</s> or [sprintf](http://ideone.com/Mgd9y)

but this may be what you really want:

```
tempCourse = data[i].course;
send(connected, &tempCourse, sizeof(tempCourse), 0);
```

(you provide the address of the `tempCourse` variable and it's bytes size in memory. see [send](http://linux.die.net/man/2/send))

(although you might need to worry about [network byte order](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Byte-Order.html))

Alternatively, if you wish to convert the `.course` struct member into a string, then try this:

```
sprintf(send_data, "%d", data[i].course);
send(connected, send_data, strlen(send_data), 0);
```

Comment: No on the compilation errors. I am compiling with -Wall and -w. From what I have read, itoa() is not portable, not ANSI C standard and not working on gcc in unix. Is this incorrect?

Comment: I am also not sure how:
    send(connected, &send_data, sizeof(send_data), 0);
helps me. The way I see it, send_data needs to be assigned the course and department so I can send that info using the send statement. That is what is giving me the problems. Passing parts of the struct.

Comment: if you look at the [itoa](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdlib/itoa/) link that i posted, there is a section on portability ~> [sprintf](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/sprintf/). And [here is how you might use it](http://ideone.com/Mgd9y). Just out of interest, do you have a reason why you *must* re-use the send_data variable for sending both data ? -eg: you could use two different variables for each call to send..

Comment: also, my bad, i was indeed incorrectly re-using your `char[]` typed `send_data` variable which was careless of me. i have edited the answer now to directly use the `.course` struct variable.

Comment: Forgive me, but I am not sure why you keep pointing me to itoa instead of atoi. That is not my problem as I see it. The only place I used atoi is to get inside the switch statement. It did an excellent job and I am past that point. On the sprintf not sure how that is used in the place of send statement. I do not think is spposed to so not sure why you are pointing me in that direction either.

Comment: The send statement within the if structure is where I am having my trouble. The if structure allows me to "print" one course within a department that may have the same course number. I can get the Department sent no problem. The course is another matter.

Comment: did you really get this to compile: `send_data =  data[i].course;` ~they would seem to be incompatible types ? -i don't keep pointing you to `itoa`; infact i gave you an example on how to convert your int to a string using `sprintf`. i initially mentioned `itoa` because according to your question, you tried this: `send_data = atoi(data[i].course);` ~ i then tried to show you a better way to send integer bytes over a network. why do you keep ingoring *that*, lol ?

Comment: ok. i edited the answer to provide a use-case for `sprintf` ~hope that works for you :)

Comment: I understand now in regards to itoa(). We were posting at the same time.

Comment: I edited my code to be current. I still cannot get the course to send to the client. I get the Dept to go. The client is in a while loop so I do not think that is the problem. Even when I blank out the lines `send(connected, &data[i].Dept, sizeof(data[i].Dept), 0);` and `tempCourse = data[i].course;` and change `send(connected, &tempCourse, sizeof(tempCourse), 0);` to `send(connected, &data[i].course, sizeof(data[i].course), 0);` I am still not getting the course to send. Any ideas?

Comment: Got it. the client was receiving stings. I used:
`sprintf(send_data, "%d", data[i].course); 
send(connected, send_data, strlen(send_data), 0);` and got it to work on the client side. Thank You.

Comment: noP. btw, don't do this: `send(connected, &data[i].Dept, sizeof(data[i].Dept), 0);` ~it's complicated but your `.Dept` struct member is actually a `char` *array*; which is infact already a pointer to the memory!  ~ so this is ok: `send(connected, data[i].Dept, strlen(data[i].Dept), 0);` ~as you originally were doing, use `strlen` incase you (quite probably) didn't fill the whole of the array,, and incase you missed it, i dropped the `&` which gets the address of a variable instead of the value. best of luck! (&mark my answer as correct if you think it is lol)

Comment: That makes sense as to why I could not get the Dept to work. It all works now. Dept and course. I did mark the feedback as hlpful. Thanks.